# Android Picasso, resize without loosing resolution & zoom / pan

Tags: android, pinchzoom, picasso

I'm using Android Picasso library from Square (http://square.github.io/picasso/).

1. How can I resize image to fit ImageView without loosing resolution? (I want to whole image inside a ImageView at first, and zoom the image without loosing the image quality)
2. Is there pinch-zoom and pan support from picasso? If not, can you recommend a good library (or android tutorial) that works well with picasso?

My reason for using Picasso is because it helps to load high resolution remote image(JPEG, on average 3.5MB in size) very well. My app needs to load the images onto 1 activity, and was suffering badly from Out of Memory exception. If anyone has a better suggestion for other library to use, I'd love to hear it!

apology if my question is stupid, I'm very new to Android. Thanks a million!﻿

Comment: Have you tried `.centerCrop()`?

Answer (score 1):

1.If you really want to provide hight quality of image, smooth moving with ImageView and regular ways to do it with Android sdk will not help you. This kind of work generally done by [OpenGL](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html) in game programming.Even if to solve your problem I would recomment U[niversal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) and use [ImageScaleType](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/366487782c2c319f1e9b2effabe227582dc07e89/library/src/com/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/assist/ImageScaleType.java) and [DisplayOptions](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Display-Options) to do your work. And for Image scaling you can try CENTER_INSIDE or CENTER_CROP look [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).

2.Google has very good documentation about [OOM](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) read this properly. For pinch zoom **Mike Ortiz** has released very good code look [this](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView).

Answer (score 0):

Picaso is good library. Yo can try .centerInside() or .fit(). There is an library [here](https://github.com/manuelstofer/pinchzoom) which works very good. Image quality actually depends on what Resolution of your image. If Image is of good quality after zooming it'll look good.
Another thing which is notable you need even after using Picaso you may face out of memory exception if you are cache images alot. So you can call skipMemoryCache()  to overcome this. 
Hope this'll help you :)